# Calculate moving averages through a dictionary of dataframes with Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, moving-average

I have an excel sheet with real time stock prices that I pull into a dataframe through XLWings. I am taking snapshots of this dataframe on set time intervals and adding each snapshot dataframe into a dictionary with the snapshot time as the key.

```
t = datetime.datetime.now()
tn = t + datetime.timedelta(seconds=1800)
dict_of_df = {}
while datetime.datetime.now()<tn:
    key_name = 'df_' + str(datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S"))
    dict_of_df[key_name] = copy.deepcopy(df)
    print(dict_of_df.keys())
    time.sleep(300)
```

I can then extract a single dataframe from it that contains the stock prices at that time. A sample output is as follows. The dataframe structure is same for each df within the dictionary. Following is a sample table. The full dataframe is 71 rows x 6 columns large:

| Ticker | Last | Bid | Ask |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AEFES | 23.06 | 23.04 | 23.06 |
| AFYON | 4.41 | 4.40 | 4.41 |
| AKBNK | 6.38 | 6.38 | 6.39 |

Now I need to calculate the moving average each stock under Ticker picked from each dataframe within the dictionary and output the results to a new, single dataframe.

Is there an efficient way of doing this other than creating a dataframe for each single stock price of each timeframe, calculating moving average and looping through them all one by one?

Now I need to calculate the moving average of prices for each stock under

Comment: Use grouby rolling

Comment: Could you specify a bit better what you want the output to look like? Is it the average of each snapshot, and the moving average over snapshots; or the moving average per snapshot, and then combined some how? Also, please don't put in pictures of your data but actual (test) data. This way we can try to fix your problem without spending ages recreating the issue.

Comment: @GijsWobben , I placed a sample 3 row table of output instead of the pic. I am taking snapshots of prices in timed-intervals. What I need to do is to take, for example, the AEFES last price for each 5 minute interval and create a moving average for it. I also need to do this for all 71 rows of prices. 

I could create 71 dataframes for each ticker that would contain all snapshot prices, create the moving averages and then consolidate them into a single dataframe but I'm asking if there's an easier and more efficient way of doing this.

Comment: You can work with data frames in a list or dictionary. Build a generalized method for moving averages that receives and returns a df then run it via a dict comprehension: `new_df_dict = { k: myfunctiontocalcMA(df) for k,df in df_dict.items() }` or directly apply MA: `new_df_dict = { k: df.assign(...) for k,df in df_dict.items() }`. Please [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) for moving averages calculation and give it a try!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might feel a little counter intuitive, but combining everything into a single dataframe IS a lot faster and efficient. I'm not sure why you're storing the timestamp as a string in de dictionary (the keys could also just be timestamps), but I'll leave that as is for now.

Try something like this:

```py
import pandas
import random
import string

# Create some test data (should look similar to yours)
tickers = ["AEFES", "AFYON", "AKBNK"] + [''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_uppercase + string.digits, k=5)) for _ in range(68)]
dfs = {
    f"df_{timestamp.strftime('%H:%M:%S')}": pandas.DataFrame(
        [
            {
                "Ticker": ticker,
                "Last": random.randint(0, 50),
                "Bid": random.randint(0, 50),
                "Ask": random.randint(0, 50),
                "Other_1": random.randint(0, 50),
                "Other_2": random.randint(0, 50),
                "Other_3": random.randint(0, 50),
            }
            for ticker in tickers
        ]
    ).set_index("Ticker")
    for timestamp in pandas.date_range("2020-01-01", periods=100, freq="5min")
}

# Combine all dataframes into a single dataframe
df = pandas.concat([df.unstack().rename(key) for key, df in dfs.items()], axis=1).T

# Take the rolling mean (= moving average) over 6 periods (= 1/2 hour)
moving_averages = df.rolling(6).mean()
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. It does work that way except one problem: All of the columns return as objects and the rolling is not possible that way. I tried astype(float) conversion but didn't work. .convert_objects(convert_numeric=True) didn't work as well. Do you have a suggestion on this?

Comment: Have a look at `to_numeric()`. If that doesn't work you'll have to show some output because it is very hard to see what's going on without it.

Comment: Selecting columns and converting using to_numeric worked perfect as well as the previous part. Thanks for all the help @gijs-wobben